# Golang alternative to c++ function with default params: multiple functions, or struct param

Tags: c++, go, idioms, function-parameter

I would like to know the best practice in Go equivalent to C++ functions binding with default params, which may be easiest for the user to see the function params(with linter help).
What do you think will be the most GO style and easiest way to use the test function ?

An example function in C++:

```cpp
void test(int x, int y=0, color=Color());
```

---

Equivalence in Go

**1. With multiple signatures:**

```golang
func test(x int)
func testWithY(x int, y int)
func testWithColor(x int, color Color)
func testWithYColor(x int, y int, color Color)
```

pro:

- The linter will show all the possibilities for test
- The compiler will take the shortest path

cons:

- Can be overwhelmed when there is a lots of params

**2. With struct parameter:**

```golang
type testOptions struct {
    X      int
    Y      int
    color  Color
}

func test(opt *testOptions)

// user 
test(&testOptions{x: 5})
```

pro:

- Only one signature
- Can specify only some values

cons:

- Need to define a struct
- The values will be set by default by the system

With the help of the module [github.com/creasty/defaults](https://github.com/creasty/defaults), there is a way to set default values (but with the cost of calling reflect in runtime).

```golang
type testOptions struct {
    X      int
    Y      int `default:"10"`
    color  Color `default:"{}"`
}

func test(opt *testOptions) *hg.Node {
    if err := defaults.Set(opt); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

pro:

- set default values

cons:

- Use of reflect in runtime

---

P.S.:
I saw the use of variadic parameters `...` or/with `interface{}` but I find it not easy to know which params to use (or maybe there is a way to indicate a params list to the linter).

Comment: To throw another option into the mix, you might be interested in the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Here's a post explaining a potential implementation in Go: https://devcharmander.medium.com/design-patterns-in-golang-the-builder-dac468a71194

Answer (score 5):

Either way will work fine, but in Go the [functional options pattern](https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/options-pattern/) might be more idiomatic for implementing such functionality.

It is based on the idea of accepting a variable amount of *WithXXX* type of functional arguments that extend of modify the behavior of the call.

```
type Test struct {
    X     int
    Y     int
    color Color
}

type TestOption func(*Test)

func test(x int, opts ...TestOption) {
    p := &Test{
        X: x,
        Y: 12,
        Color: defaultColor,
    }
    for _, opt := range opts {
        opt(p)
    }
    p.runTest()
}

func main() {
    test(12)
    test(12, WithY(34))
    test(12, WithY(34), WithColor(Color{1, 2, 3}))
}

func WithY(y int) TestOption {
    return func(p *Test) {
        p.Y = y
    }
}

func WithColor(c Color) TestOption {
    return func(p *Test) {
        p.color = c
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this idea is nice to build a complexe object.
My goal is to provide a very easy api to call binding function with default parameter.
The first option seems the easiest to understand for newbie, but I keep in mind your options which is very nice for default parameter and object build.
Question: How can I tell the linter that WithY can be used in test ? (for an easiest use)

Comment: The “functional options pattern” is usable, but over time its flaws become apparent — it's a huge amount of boilerplate to maintain, in exchange for essentially no gain in usability. (For example, what happens if you pass two different `WithY` options, or two different `WithColor` options?) There is a reason new APIs tend to opt (ha!) for the struct argument instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your option 1 is a good idiomatic choice if the result is only a handful of functions. I also think the functional options pattern is a fine choice, it is often used in factory functions.

To add another choice, this question might be an indication that the code needs to be re-factored. Should `test()` be a method on a type which knows the optional parameters?

One of the [go proverbs](https://go-proverbs.github.io/) is "make the zero value useful", so a type with its zero value is assumed to mean use the default. If `0` is a valid value for your `int` type then consider `*int`, the point is to avoid referencing fields where you want to keep the default.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const (
    defaultY     = 10
    defaultColor = "blue"
)

type Color string

type Thing struct {
    Y     int
    Color Color
}

func (t Thing) getY() int {
    if t.Y == 0 {
        return defaultY
    }
    return t.Y
}

func (t Thing) getColor() Color {
    if t.Color == "" {
        return defaultColor
    }
    return t.Color
}

func (t Thing) Test(x int) {
    fmt.Println(x, t.getY(), t.getColor())
}

func main() {
    Thing{}.Test(12)
    Thing{Y: 11}.Test(12)
    Thing{Y: 11, Color: "red"}.Test(12)
}

// 12 10 blue
// 12 11 blue
// 12 11 red
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this option is nice to build an object.
The linter will show the different functions available.